# Adding Metric Source to Autoscale in AzureCLI for WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to add an autoscale rule to my app webapp, where I need to scale up 1 instance based on the number of messages from a service bus queue (metric source). I am hoping if someone has insight on how this can be achieved using Azure CLI. The microsoft documentation on autoscale doesn't really cover how I can add metric source as part of the condition.

From the UI:
[Metric Scale option from UI]

[image]

I am trying to to achieve something similar to this:

az monitor autoscale rule create  --resource-group MyResourceGroup   `--resource MyPlan` 
--resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms' `--autoscale-name MyAutoScale`   
--condition "MessageCount > 20 avg 5m"   `
--scale out 2

Looking at the json file, I am trying to get specify these fields in Azure cli

[image]

Any help on this topic would be highly apprciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

while creating the **`az monitor autoscale rule`** you have to specify the valid **`--condition`** to process your metrics.

Check the [supported Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported) to achieve this.

Refer [Service bus metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftservicebusnamespaces) to process the **autoscale**.